# 1 All instances of a component reference the first instance instead of itself; 2 Children props get updated only after calling parent's setState twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-props, react-state

**UPDATE**: I easily fixed the first issue by providing unique names for all the 'Rating' components, but the question about 2 x setState fixing props remains open.

I actually have two questions. The second one emerged from trying to solve the first one.
The initial problem was that 'this' in each of the onChange Rating's property in each of the SongScoring components pointed to the first instance of the SongScoring class instead of itself:

Parent code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Assess.css';
import { Accordion } from 'react-bootstrap';
import SongScoring from './SongScoring';

class Assess extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const songs = [
      {
        track: "song1",
      },
      {
        track: "song2",
      },
      {
        track: "song3",
      },
      {
        track: "song4",
      },
    ]

    this.state = {
      songs: songs,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="root">
        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
          {
            this.state.songs.map((song, index) => (
              <SongScoring song={song} key={index.toString()} index={index} />
            ))
          }
        </Accordion>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Assess;
```

Child code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './SongScoring.css';
import { Accordion, Card, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import Rating from '@material-ui/lab/Rating';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

const labels = {
  0.5: 'Unpleasant',
  1: 'Bearable',
  1.5: 'Bearable+',
  2: 'Intriguing',
  2.5: 'Intriguing+',
  3: 'Ok',
  3.5: 'Ok+',
  4: 'Pleasant',
  4.5: 'Pleasant+',
  5: 'Excellent',
};

class SongScoring extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      song: props.song,
      key: props.index.toString(),
      score: props.song.score || 0,
      hover: props.song.score || -1,
      onChange: this.props.onChange,
      onChangeActive: this.props.onChangeActive
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Card>
          <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} variant="link" eventKey={this.state.key}>
            {this.state.key}
            <Rating name="read-only" value={this.state.score} precision={0.5} readOnly />
          </Accordion.Toggle>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={this.state.key}>
            <Card.Body style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', lineHeight: '1' }}>
              <Container>
                <Row className='scoring-row'>
                  <ReactPlayer
                    url="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3"
                    width="400px"
                    height="50px"
                    playing={false}
                    controls={true}
                    style={{ outline: 'none' }}
                  />
                </Row>
                <Row className='scoring-row'>
                  <Rating
                    name="song-rating"
                    value={this.state.score}
                    precision={0.5}
                    onChange={(event, newScore) => {
                      this.setState({
                        score: newScore
                      });
                    }}
                    onChangeActive={(event, newHover) => {
                      this.setState({
                        hover: newHover
                      });
                    }}
                    style={{ marginTop: '40px' }}
                  />
                </Row>
                <Row className='scoring-row'>
                  {this.state.score !== 0 && <Box>{labels[this.state.hover !== -1 ? this.state.hover : this.state.score]}</Box>}
                </Row>
              </Container>
            </Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default SongScoring;
```

After multiple iterations of trying to solve this problem by changing from arrow functions and binding, putting onChange and onChangeActive into the state etc. I finally decided to try to solve this problem by passing the onChange and onChangeActive functions from the parent to the child.

This is what I came up with (there is console.log instead of setState in onChange and onChangeActive, but what we care about is 'this' reference really):

Parent code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Assess.css';
import { Accordion } from 'react-bootstrap';
import SongScoring from './SongScoring';

class Assess extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const songs = [
      {
        track: "song1",
      },
      {
        track: "song2",
      },
      {
        track: "song3",
      },
      {
        track: "song4",
      },
    ]

    this.songScoring = [];
    const onChange = [];
    const onChangeActive = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
      this.songScoring.push(React.createRef());
      onChange.push(function (event, newScore) {
        console.log("onChange: ", this);
      });
      onChangeActive.push(function (event, newHover) {
        console.log("onChangeActive: ", this);
      });
    }

    this.state = {
      songs: songs,
      onChange: onChange,
      onChangeActive: onChangeActive
    };

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.songScoring);
    const onChange = [];
    const onChangeActive = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.songs.length; i++) {
      onChange.push(this.state.onChange[i].bind(this.songScoring[i], 1));
      onChangeActive.push(this.state.onChangeActive[i].bind(this.songScoring[i]));
    }    
    this.setState({
      onChange: onChange,
      onChangeActive: onChangeActive
    });//, () => this.setState({unicorn: 1}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="root">
        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
          {
            this.state.songs.map((song, index) => (
              <SongScoring song={song} ref={this.songScoring[index]} key={index.toString()} index={index} onChange={this.state.onChange[index]} onChangeActive={this.state.onChangeActive[index]} />
            ))
          }
        </Accordion>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Assess;
```

Child code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './SongScoring.css';
import { Accordion, Card, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import Rating from '@material-ui/lab/Rating';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

const labels = {
  0.5: 'Unpleasant',
  1: 'Bearable',
  1.5: 'Bearable+',
  2: 'Intriguing',
  2.5: 'Intriguing+',
  3: 'Ok',
  3.5: 'Ok+',
  4: 'Pleasant',
  4.5: 'Pleasant+',
  5: 'Excellent',
};

class SongScoring extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        song: props.song,
        key: props.index.toString(),
        score: props.song.score || 0,
        hover: props.song.score || -1,
        onChange: this.props.onChange,
        onChangeActive: this.props.onChangeActive
    }
    
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if (prevProps.onChange !== this.state.onChange){
        this.setState({
            onChange: prevProps.onChange,
            onChangeActive: prevProps.onChangeActive
        })
    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
        <>
          <Card> 
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} variant="link" eventKey={this.state.key}>
              {this.state.key}
              <Rating name="read-only" value={this.state.score} precision={0.5} readOnly />
            </Accordion.Toggle>
            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={this.state.key}>
              <Card.Body style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', lineHeight: '1' }}>
                <Container>
                  <Row className='scoring-row'>
                    <ReactPlayer
                      url="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3"
                      width="400px"
                      height="50px"
                      playing={false}
                      controls={true}
                      style={{outline: 'none'}}
                    />
                  </Row>
                  <Row className='scoring-row'>
                    <Rating
                      name="song-rating"
                      value={this.state.score}
                      precision={0.5}
                      onChange={this.state.onChange}
                      onChangeActive={this.state.onChangeActive}
                      style={{ marginTop: '40px' }}
                    />
                  </Row>
                  <Row className='scoring-row'>
                    {this.state.score !== 0 && <Box>{labels[this.state.hover !== -1 ? this.state.hover : this.state.score]}</Box>}
                  </Row>
                </Container>
              </Card.Body>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
          </Card>
        </>
      );
  }
}

export default SongScoring;
```

In this setting, console.log in onChange and onChangeActive output both 'undefined'.

Now, if I uncomment the fragment: '//, () => this.setState({unicorn: 1}));' (unicorn is a dummy, unused variable) in the parent, console.log of onChange and onChangeActive prints out nicely 'this' as the references for respective SongScoring components.

Therefore my questions are:

- what's going on here, in both problems? Is it a bug of the 'Rating' component?
- how to solve my initial problem more efficiently than by using the second approach with the uncommented fragment?

**UPDATE**: I easily fixed the first issue by providing unique names for all the 'Rating' components, but the question about 2 x setState fixing props remains open.